# How to color a row in tabeview if i already have some event on that table?

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, event-handling

I have this event that do something when user clicks on a row

```
 public void updateList(PoliseTable poliseTable) {

    poliseTable.getTableView().setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<PolisePOJO> row = new TableRow<>();
  
        row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 1 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
                PolisePOJO rowData = row.getItem();                 
                List<PredmetiPOJO> predmetiList = PredmetiDAO.loadPredmete(rowData.getId());
                predmetiList.stream().forEach(e
                        -> predmetiTable.getPredmetiTable().getItems().add(new PredmetiPOJO(e.getId(),
                                e.getName(), e.getPlace(), e.getAdress(), e.getRegNumber(), e.getValue()))
                );
            }
        });
        return row;
    });
}
```

So method above works fine now i want to color rows based on some column value this is what i tried

```
    public void customizeColorRow(TableColumn column) {
    poliseTable.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<PolisePOJO>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(PolisePOJO polise, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(polise, empty);
            if (polise == null) {
                setStyle("");
            } else if (polise.getStatus().equals("1")) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: tomato;");
            } else { 
                setStyle("");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When i call `customizeColorRow` method it doesn't work, but when i remove `updateList` method than it works. I'm not very good al lambda's so maybe i'm doing something wrong.
So how can i have both functionalities working at the same time?

Comment: The problem is you are changing row factories. You can override `updateItem`method in your first row factory definition

Comment: Btw you don't need `stream()` for `forEach` in your case. You can simply add all your list if you don't need to create new objects like `predmetiTable.getPredmetiTable().getItems().addAll(predmetiList)`

Comment: @Alex Hi Alex, but i already have `override` annotaion above `updateItem` method. What did you mean exactly?

Comment: You are setting row factory twice. In first fragment with mouseclick event defining and in second with `updateItem` overriding. You should do it in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the comments, a `TableView` only has one row factory. If you set the row factory twice, it will only have the second factory. Simply use a `rowFactory` that provides `TableRow` instances with all the functionality you want.

```
poliseTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<PolisePOJO> row = new TableRow<>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(PolisePOJO polise, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(polise, empty);
            if (polise == null) {
                setStyle("");
            } else if (polise.getStatus().equals("1")) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: tomato;");
            } else { 
                setStyle("");
            }
        }
    };

    row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        if (event.getClickCount() == 1 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
            PolisePOJO rowData = row.getItem();                 
            List<PredmetiPOJO> predmetiList = PredmetiDAO.loadPredmete(rowData.getId());
            predmetiList.forEach(e
                    -> predmetiTable.getPredmetiTable().getItems().add(new PredmetiPOJO(e.getId(),
                            e.getName(), e.getPlace(), e.getAdress(), e.getRegNumber(), e.getValue()))
            );
        }
    });
    return row;
});
```

If you want to keep the functionality separated, you can register a listener with the `itemProperty()` instead of overriding `updateItem()`, and "decorate" the existing row factory:

```
public void updateList(TableView<PolisePOJO> poliseTable) {

    poliseTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<PolisePOJO> row = getRowFromTable(tv);

        row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 1 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
                PolisePOJO rowData = row.getItem();                 
                List<PredmetiPOJO> predmetiList = PredmetiDAO.loadPredmete(rowData.getId());
                predmetiList.stream().forEach(e
                        -> predmetiTable.getPredmetiTable().getItems().add(new PredmetiPOJO(e.getId(),
                                e.getName(), e.getPlace(), e.getAdress(), e.getRegNumber(), e.getValue()))
                );
            }
        });
        return row;
    });
}
```

and

```
public void customizeColorRow() {
    poliseTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<PolisePOJO> row = getRowFromTable(tv) ;
        row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldPolise, polise) -> {
            if (polise == null) {
                row.setStyle("");
            } else if (polise.getStatus().equals("1")) {
                row.setStyle("-fx-background-color: tomato;");
            } else { 
                row.setStyle("");
            }
        });
        return row ;
    });
}
```

with

```
private TableRow<PolisePOJO> getRowFromTable(TableView<PolisePOJO> table) {
    Callback<TableView<PolisePOJO>, TableRow<PolisePOJO>> rowFactory = table.getRowFactory();
    if (rowFactory == null) {
        return new TableRow<>();
    } else {
        return rowFactory.call(table);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, now i understand what is the problem, but your code dosen't compile, i get error when creating `TableRow<PolisePOJO> row = new TableRow<>()`.  Here is the error `cannot infer type arguments for TableRow<T> reason: cannot use <> with annonymous inner classes in sources 1.8` . So when i remove diamond and `override` annotation it does compile but stil doesn't work

Comment: @NemJov JDK 1.8 is very old. If you're still using that for some reason, use `TableRow<PolisePOJO> row = new TableRow<PolisePOJO>() { ... } ;`. In any case, there is no need to remove `@Override`. Elaborate on "doesn't work"

Comment: Okay that actually worked i was convinced that in java 1.8 you don't have to put identifier in second diamond. Thank you James. Do you have any advice for handling logic in row factory? I'm just thinking if i want something else to do with rows i will have to type code in that existing method and will be very long and hard to read

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your effort to actually type the code.